# To retrieve image from database using php

Tags: php, image

I uploaded images into a table sucessfully. All I want to do now is to retrieve the last uploaded image from the table and to display it on the screen.
To do so, I used the following code.

```
$sql=mysql_query("Select * from storeimg where id=(select max(id) from storeimg)");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
header("content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $row[img];
```

But, when i run the code, the image is not displayed. Also, no error messages shown.I'm just getting a blank screen.Help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_*`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: `$row[img]` should be `$row['img']` (assuming that column actually exists). Also the header would be better as `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`. Lastly, don't select * if you don't need *, just `SELECT img` if that's all you need. (`SELECT *` is always a bad idea, avoid it if you can)

Comment: I would advice not to store images in tables.  Put images in a directory and just store a path value pointing to your directory + image.

Comment: Could you show us the structure of the table storeimg ?

Comment: I made those changes. Now, I'm getting an img like icon on the screen intead of the original image stored in the database. I couldn't find where the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you might need to unescape the binary data that you stored in the database, depending on how you inserted the data into the record.

I would compare the data before it gets escaped and inserted, with the data that gets selected, and see if there are any differences. I've had a similar problem with PostgreSQL and this was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for ur response ,Mr.Brain Moore. I hav inserted the image into the table like uploading an image from the system.

Comment: But, I couldn't get ur idea of comparing the data. Can u pls be specific?

Comment: Rambo, I would take an image to compare, and put it on your server. Then I would upload that image with your script. Then pull the data from the database, and take the data from the image column $row['img'] and put it in a file. file_put_contents('test.jpg', $row['img']);

Then, in a console, use `diff orig.jpg test.jpg` and see if there's any difference in the data. If so, then the image data is getting munged when inserted into the database.